# how to create a hash function which can be parametrized?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to create a hash function that is supported by template types T and E.
I use:

```
  namespace std {
   namespace tr1 {
    template<class T, class E> struct hash<my_class<T, E> >
    {
      public:
       size_t operator()(const my_class<T, E>& k) const
           {
               return ((hash<T>()(k.a()))^ (hash<E>()(k.x()) << 1) >> 1);
       }
     };
    }
  }
```

but I get errors such as:

```
 In file included from g.cpp:1:
 g.h:35: error: ‘hash’ is not a template
 g.h:36: error: explicit specialization of non-template ‘hash’
 g.h:76: error: ‘hash’ is not a template
 g.h:76: error: ‘hash’ is not a template type
```

Is there no way to specialize a hash function so that it can use a template?

If not, how would I construct a hash function which is based on generic types T and E?

EDIT: Someone answered below, but not quite to my question. I am interested in being able to define a hash function which itself uses generic types. Something like hash< some_class < T > > where T is a generic type.

Comment: **Why** are you adding to namespaces `std::tr1`?? I don't think it's intended to do this without any really good reason.

Comment: BTW: you should add comments to mark the line numbers so that we can match the error lines to source-code lines.

Answer (score 2):

*hash* is in namespace `std` not in namespace `std::tr1`. See the snippet from [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) for an example on how to specialize it (of course you can also partial specialize it):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

struct S
{
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
};

namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<S>
    {
        typedef S argument_type;
        typedef std::size_t value_type;

        value_type operator()(argument_type const& s) const
        {
            value_type const h1 ( std::hash<std::string>()(s.first_name) );
            value_type const h2 ( std::hash<std::string>()(s.last_name) );
            return h1 ^ (h2 << 1);
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    S s;
    s.first_name = "Bender";
    s.last_name =  "Rodriguez";
    std::hash<S> hash_fn;

    std::cout << "hash(s) = " << hash_fn(s) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Judging by OP's previous question, they are using the TR1 unordered maps and sets. So the namespace `std::tr1` would be right.

Comment: That's not quite what I want. I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score -3):

It's not a good idea to pollute any standard namespace with your own functions. Just put the class in your own namespace and you can do whatever you want. In your case, just make your own class API-compatible with the standard hash. Additionally, there's no problem in calling the standard hash from within your own hash.